# How is "! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." produced (technically)?

Tags: errors, lists, latex-base

Lists in LaTeX test for `\item` before their `\end{list}`. I want to know **the chain of events leading to this error**. From my analysis, I came to the following, but got lost at `\@noitemerr`.

**Sources**

- texdoc source2e
- kpsewhich lterror.dtx
- kpsewhichltlists.dtx

## The Premise

Is the error produced here, because there `\end{itemize}` is reached while still in math mode or vertical mode (in any case, NOT horizontal mode)? Correct?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Test.
\begin{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

## Stop Reading Here if Scared of the LaTeX Kernel

I am not sure where the trigger is. The thing I found which seems to cause an error is inside of `\endtrivlist`.

Chain of events: `\list -> \@trivlist -> \trivlist > \endlist -> \endtrivlist`

### \endtrivlist

This snippet is checks for math mode, something that `\item` does not support.

```
\ifhmode\unskip \par
\else
  \@inmatherr{\end{\@currenvir}}% Good grief???
\fi
```

My understanding is that `\end{itemized}` would be passed to `\@inmatherr` if this were called within `\begin{itemize}\end{itemize}`. Correct?

## The Error Chain

### \@inmatherr

```
\gdef\@inmatherr#1{% #1=\macro, handover to \@latex@error
   \relax
   \ifmmode
    \@latex@error{Command \protect#1 invalid in math mode}\@ehc
   \fi}
```

### \@latex@error

```
\gdef\@latex@error#1#2{% #1=Command \macro invalid in math mode #2=\@ehc
    \GenericError{%
       \space\space\space\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces
    }{%
       LaTeX Error: #1%
    }{%
       See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.%
    }{#2}%
}
```

### \@noitemerr

How did we get here? What am I missing?

```
\gdef\@noitemerr{% how do we get here?
  \@latex@error{Something's wrong--perhaps a missing %
  \protect\item}\@ehc}
```

### \@ehc

```
\gdef\@ehc{%
  Try typing \space <return> %
  \space to proceed.\MessageBreak
  If that doesn't work, type \space X <return> \space to quit.}
```

### \GenericError

The thing that prints to the console and log?

```
% This macro takes four arguments: a continuation,
% an error message, where to go for further information, and the help
% information.  It displays the error message, and sets the error help
% (the result of typing |h| to the prompt), and does a horrible hack
% to turn the last context line (which by default is the only context
% line) into just three dots.  This could be made more efficient.
\bgroup
\lccode`\@=`\ %
\lccode`\~=`\ %
\lccode`\}=`\ %
\lccode`\{=`\ %
\lccode`\T=`\T%
\lccode`\H=`\H%
\catcode`\ =11\relax%
\lowercase{%
\egroup%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\GenericError}[4]{%
\begingroup%
\immediate\write\@unused{}%
\def\MessageBreak{^^J}%
\set@display@protect%
\edef%
%    %<-------------------do not delete this space!------------------->%
\@err@                                                                 %
{{#4}}%
\errhelp
%    %<-------------------do not delete this space!------------------->%
\@err@                                                                 %
\let
%    %<-------------------do not delete this space!------------------->%
\@err@                                                                 %
\@empty
\def\MessageBreak{^^J#1}%
\def~{\errmessage{%
#2.^^J^^J%
#3^^J%
Type  H <return>  for immediate help%
%    %<-------------------do not delete this space!------------------->%
\@err@                                                                 %
}}%
~%
\endgroup}%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latex is explictly testing for that input and raising an error.

`\endtrivlist` does

```
 \if@newlist
    \@noitemerr
```

so that reads as:

> if it is still a 'new list' by the end of the list, generate an error that there is no `\item`.

999 times out of 1000 when you get the perhaps a missing item error, it is not due to a missing `\item` but this is the one case the error does actually give the correct cause.

Comment: Did you count all of the times :)? "999 times out of 1000" It looks like `\@trivlist` calls this too as a condition of `\if@inlabel`.

Comment: I counted how many times I have had to explain to a user why they got that error, on this site, and comp.text.tex and texhax mailing list and the latex bug address and...., yes:-)

Comment: @JonathanKomar by far the most common route to get `\@noitemerror` is to call `\addvspace` when you are not in vertical mode, so if you do `center` environment inside `\mbox` or a table `l` column or `verbatim` or a section head, or any other kind of display construct that is adding vertical space at a point that you can not add vertical space you get this error. From a user view (and even a code source view) suggesting the error condition is related to `\item` is not that helpful. In 1985 saving a dozen bytes by re-using the existing error message probably made sense....

Comment: Haha sorry about that! You have to admit that this is not very intuitive. I have to assume for now that `\item` calls `\newlistfalse` until I have a look at the definitions.